# Iterating again, prime factors loop, python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, primes

I recently made a function in python that will give me all the factors of any number you choose in python. I would like to modify it now to only show the prime factors. The function I have currently is:

```
def prime_factors(n):
L = []
i = range(1, n+1)
for x in i:
    if n % x == 0:
        L.append(x)
return L
```

Now, to find the prime factors, I wanted to re-iterate through L, and remove any numbers from L, who when divided by any numbers up to itself, the remainder would be 0.

So, essentially, I just want to take the list I have now, after I've appended it, then divide each value in the list by every number up to THAT number to make sure it isn't divisible by anything with a remainder of 0.

I've tried:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    L = []
    i = range(1, n+1)
    for x in i:
        if n % x == 0:
            L.append(x)
    for y in L:
        for x in i:
            if y % x == 0:
                L.remove(y)
    return L
```

Also, I have tried splitting it into 2 different functions...

```
def prime_factors(n):
    L = []
    i = range(2, n)
        for x in i:
            if n % x == 0:
                L.append(x)
    return L

def prime(n):
     L = prime_factors(n)
     i = range(2, n)
         for y in L:
            for x in i:
                if x % y == 0:
                    L.remove(x)
     return L
```

I've tried placing the returns in different places, I've tried flipping the order of loops, no matter what, I can't figure out how to run the list L through another check to see if the values in it are divisible by 0...

Comment: Your initial code for the list of factors could use a shorter loop.  Every time you find a factor `x` you have also found a second factor `n / x`.  You can add both to the list.  That halves the upper limit of your loop.  If you want the factors in order then sort your list at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your prime_factors function as follows:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    L = []
    i = range(2, n+1)  # start from 2 as it is the first prime
    for x in i:
        if n % x == 0:
            L.append(x)
            # loop added
            while n%x == 0:
                n = n/x
        # break as no further factors are possible
        if n == 1:
            break
    return L
```

Now, what the while n%x == 0 does is, it removes powers of some factor from the original number.

For example,
n = 24 = 2*2*2*3
n%2 == 0, so L = [2] and n becomes 3 [This makes sure 4 or 8, which are non-primes are not appended to L]

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply a function that return True/False for prime numbers

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

def prime_factors(n):
    L = []
    i = range(1, n+1)
    for x in i:
        if n % x == 0:
            if is_prime(x):
                L.append(x)
    return L
```

Comment: If I just wanted to ammend my code above though, how would I go about doing it? I really would want to do it by removing the non-primes from the list of factors. Plus, I understand better based on the code I already have.